# android how to build listview into drawer fragment content?

Tags: java, android

I need to creat **listView**, when user click to element of drawer navigation. How i can do this? ALso i need to ovwerload this **listView** after user will scroll down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there is a full example on the official website on how creating a `NavigationDrawer` with a `ListView` in it :

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

Once this down work on your scroll down problematic ...